# Irregular number of keys array

Tags: php, arrays

I have got array with irregular number of keys, for example:

```
array: [ 0 => true, 2 => false, 3 => true, 8 => true ]
```

I want to see array like this:

```
array: [ 0 => true, 1 => false, 2 => true, 3 => true ]
```

How i can do this?

Comment: Use `array_values`.

Comment: what do you want, exactly?

Comment: This might be an XY issue. If you just want to be able to iterate over this array, use foreach. If you want the array keys to be reset, array_values is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a builtin [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) PHP function, as shown below:

```
$arr = array_values($oldArray);
```

Comment: It seems that works, so thanks

Answer (score -1):

array_values does that :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
$fixedArray = array_values($arr);
```

Comment: had a $ on the method, fixed.